# Problems with dissolved shapefiles in Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, gis, google-earth-engine, geemap

I created a single dissolved polygon shapefile out of a set of smaller polygons in ArcGIS and imported it into Google Earth Engine using geemap (Python API). I wanted to extract values from every pixel in the dissolved shapefile using the ee.Image.sampleRegions function.

However, upon closer inspection, it appears that the function only sampled one of the smaller polygons, even though I imported it as a single shapefile. When I show it on the map and select it, it seems like it should be working as a single polygon.

Does anyone know why this could be? It is a large area (about 20,000 hectares), if that matters.